# Rename multiple R Markdowns using map() in purrr and makeDataReport()

Tags: r, r-markdown, purrr

I want to rename a list of R Markdowns from a group split. Each dataframe has their own name in the list. My question is that I want to use `makeDataReport()` to generate a R Markdown report for each group split but the function gives me an error on renaming the new R Markdown output.

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(dataReporter)
split(penguins, penguins$island) %>% 
  map(makeDataReport)

Data report generation is finished. Please wait while your output file is being rendered.
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : 
  The file name(s) to be used by dataReporter, dataReporter_.x__i__.Rmd and dataReporter_.x__i__.pdf, is(are) already in use. We recommend trying one of the following solutions: 
 - rename your dataReporter output file using the "file" option 
 - Add a volume number to your file name using the "vol" option 
 - check that you do not want to keep the original file and if so, use makeDataReport() with argument replace = TRUE
```

There's a parameter in `makeDataReport` I can change the output R Markdown name `makeDataReport(dataframe, file = "Torgersen.Rmd")` . But how do I do it in a dynamic way - renaming all of them effectively?

Expectd output:

```
Torgersen.Rmd
Biscoe.Rmd
Dream.Rmd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pengiuns <- split(penguins, penguins$island) 
pengiuns %>% 
  map(~makeDataReport(., file = paste0(unique(.$island),".Rmd")))
```

#Edit to use the names instead of the column

```
pengiunsList <- split(penguins, penguins$island) 
pengiunsList %>% 
  map2(names(pengiunsList), ~makeDataReport(.x, file = paste0(.y,".Rmd")))
```

#Edit2: A third solution I didnt know about till just now

```
pengiunsList <- split(penguins, penguins$island) 
pengiunsList %>% 
  imap(~makeDataReport(.x, file = paste0(.y,".Rmd")))
```

Comment: Sorry to trouble you one thing. Is it possible to get the `name(pengiuns)` from the list instead of using `unique(.$island)`? @zimia

Comment: Yes but you will need to create a separate list holding the names and use the `map2` function